# @attribute [AllowAnonymous] in Blazor server-side component has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a fresh Blazor server-side project with .NET Core 3.0 and have closed down the application for non-authenticated users.

I am now trying to allow anonymous access to Index.razor component by placing [AllowAnonymous] at the top of the file. This however, does not seem to do anything.

**Scenario**

After using the default Blazor template "WeatherForecast" I added the following to **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

This piece of code blocks all requests toward my application if the user is not authenticated.

After adding that piece of code I would like to open up the default **Index.razor** component for non-authenticated users. I do that by adding **@attribute [AllowAnonymous]** to Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
```

**App.razor**

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
</Router>
```

**Expected result**

When running my application non-authenticated users would be allowed to visit the index page at https://localhost:XXXX

**Actual result**

My users are forwarded to my OpenIdConnect URI.

Comment: How do you configure your `AuthorizationView` ? You can probably work around with the `NotAuthorized` section

Comment: Do you mean in the App.razor component?

Comment: Yes I do, To enable Authorization you have an `AuthorizationView` in your layout right ?

Comment: Yes, I have added my code in App.razor component to my question.

Comment: I was talking about [AuthorizeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component) not [AuthorizeRouteView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component) sorry for the missspelling. But actually you can use a combinason of both with more than 1 policy. You can add an anonymous policy for exemple.

Comment: From my point of view, that would make it kinda contradiction to what it should supposely do. [AuthorizeView(Police="AllowAnonymous")]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202167/discussion-between-agua-from-mars-and-anonymous).

Comment: Related ASP.NET Core github issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13709#issuecomment-552609697)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor using Azure AD authentication allowing anonymous access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768399/blazor-using-azure-ad-authentication-allowing-anonymous-access)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of entire Blazor app as a single html page in terms of ASP.NET Core. In other words, Blazor app is hosted in single html page. That's why it is called Single Page Application framework :)

If user does not have access to that single page, any Blazor code does not matter.

---

`@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` only works within Blazor app, but `services.AddMvcCore(options => options.Filter.Add(...))` disallows users to access the single page that hosts your Blazor App.

It's the same as with any other SPA framework. If you have a React/Angular/Vue app hosted in a HTML file, you need to make sure users have access to the HTML file.

I think you will have to do following:

1. Modify to ASP.NET Core authorization to authorize your other Controller/Pages, but allow anonymous access to your entire blazor app (all other routes).

   I haven't tried, but something like this instead auhtorization filter

   ```
   app.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
   app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();

   app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AllowAnonymous()
      .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
   ```
2. Modify you Blazor app to authorize all pages except index.