# Blazor using Azure AD authentication allowing anonymous access

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm currently writing a (Server side) Blazor application that includes the default AzureAD Authentication.

This works well for authenticated users - challenging on the entrance (`_Host.cshtml`) file, redirecting and then back once authenticated.

I need to have a couple of pages *not* requiring authentication - I don't want the user being challenged and redirected to Microsoft.

What is the correct way to do this? I have experimented with the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`, the `AllowAnonymousToPage` razor pages options, nothing seems to stop the challenge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my setup for Authentication (ConfigureServices):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddTelerikBlazor();
}
```

And then the appropriate part in Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour of Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found what I had to do was add the following to _Hosts.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

Once I did this authorization was no longer required on any of the pages by default and I could then add it to the pages where I wanted to require it.

For example if you wanted to secure the Counter.razor page just add an Authorize attribute to the top:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

So now if you tried to access the counter page you will get a Not authorized message.

If you want to remove the counter link when the user is not logged in modify the NavMenu.razor and surround the Counter link with an `<AuthorizeView> </AuthorizeView>` as so:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Ideally I would have liked to just opt out of authorization for the index page and have everything else secured by default but I could not find a way to get that to work. If I tried adding the `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` to the Index.razor page it seemed to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LarryDev , I've discovered that removing the AuthorizeFilter (in Startup.cs) specifically the `RequireAuthenticatedUser` method as this sets it site-wide does the trick.
Then simply putting the `AuthorizeAttribute` on each Razor **page** (components aren't used in routing).
This way the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` is not required on the __Hosts page.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to disable authentication on all pages. This can be done by commenting the fallback policy out in "Program.cs".

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => 
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Then, on your individual razor pages, add the following code:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @*code for authenticated users here*@
        I am logged in
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @*code for unauthenticated users here*@
        Please log in
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

This will allow you to retain complete functionality of all components and functions within you app.

I do not recommend adding the following to your "_Host.cshtml" file as this causes buttons and components to longer function/display correctly

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

Hope this helps. I am using Blazor server with dotnet 6.

Comment: While this might work, I don't think the solution is proper - you're essentially saying unauthorized = anonymous - this is incorrect and will also cause a blowout in your code structure on the anonymous side.