# Anonymus page in Blazor Server App while authenticated using Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side, anonymous

I am currently writing blazor server application, authenticated with Azure AD (Not Azure AD B2c). There are some pages that I want to make accessible publicly.

Current Behavior: If application is not authenticated. It's directly redirect to Azure AD login page.

I have tried following to make page anonymous, But it's not working

```
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

Comment: please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768399/blazor-using-azure-ad-authentication-allowing-anonymous-access) it may help you

Comment: Are you still looking for  help on this question

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Yes, It's not working