# Blazor ServerApp Azure b2C - how to Allow Anonymous Access To Website and not display SigninSignUp B2C Login page on web start

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, azure-ad-b2c

**A Useful Question For Blazor Server App AD B2C first timers**

Where and how to configure or programmatically change default out the box behavior of Azure B2c on a blazor Server App - to allow anonymous guest access to the website without the website redirecting to the SignInSignUp B2CLogin page?

**Summary**

1. Ad B2C - Default Behavior is hit f5 run the signin page shows.
2. Desired Behaviour: allow anon access and secure auth access

**Research**

After spending a while researching AD B2C and playing around with razor and .net apps it was fine and really awesome - the issue really only occurred and related to Blazor Server App + AD b2C.
Ive been coding  Blazor Server Apps and having great fun but this was the first time with auth and AD B2C so there was certainly a lot of caveats overlooked in guidance's you have to find out to make it all work.

**Clarity Steps to Reproduce**

So that the question is clear, I will post the steps to reproduce and the pre-requisites what this is and how it was arrived at - using the approach and tech available as of April 2022.

**Technology**

- Blazor Server App Using VS022 and .net 6 LTS  with AZURE AD b2C

**Pre-Requisites Azure B2C**

- Azure AD B2C  - Registered App
- Identity Providers
- Azure AD B2C - User Worfklow

**Project Creation and configuration of the Blazor Server App with VS2022 .Net 6 LTS**

**Blazor Server App  Project**

- Vs2022 > New Project: Blazor Server App
- Authentication Type: MicroSoft Identity Platform
- Configure the BlazorServer AppSettings with the  dotnet msidentity tool wizard.The default settings it puts in AppSettings.json  will be fine to test auth access default behavior

**Default Behaviour:**

- Hit F5 - On Web Page Load Redirects to the Azure B2C Login page
- [Image of default behavior - redirect to Azure b2c login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An6Gz.png)
- User has to signup and signin On success Website redirected back user is logged in [Image of user logged in web access provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Adm.png)

**Desired behavior:**

- Hit F5 - On Web Page Load Anon access with choice to login
- [Image of desired behavior website loads and user can click login to view secure content using Azure b2C for authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tqRm.png)

**Attributions**

- I was able to reach my out the box default solution above with assistance from resources: Michael Washington MSVP
  https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/42

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

**within Program.cs**

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();
```

the UseAuthorization will trigger the redirect to the Azure B2C Login page. This could be commented out and then it will load the website and allow anonymous access  and allow a use to click on a login lnik etc.

**Useful Resources:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Found in an answer to Azure Directory to Blazor Server App
[Blazor using Azure AD authentication allowing anonymous access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768399/blazor-using-azure-ad-authentication-allowing-anonymous-access)

Thank you to those guys for making the effort to post and answer that fantastic.

So then it would make sense the same approach would work for
Azure Directory B2C and low and behold it did.

When i understood my question better i was able to use better words to describe  and search and finally something that works- im sure it's not the only answer but its 1 answer.

add the following to _Hosts.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

to secure the .razor page just add an Authorize attribute to the top:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

So now if you tried to access the counter page you will get a Not authorized message.

Devs if there are any others please do add them.
many thanks

Comment: Worked fine in .NET6 (core 6). But it is not working in .NET 7.